# In Portal 2, can you transfer ps3 saved data to a pc to continue playing with same profile?

Tags: pc, ps3, portal-2

Since you get both versions is it possible to start on one platform and move to another? Is there a way or need to convert files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5477-WPJM-9388#ps3cloud

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily if you put your save on a USB drive and then put it on your computer you might be able to transfer it to work on Steam