# Sync progress in Portal 2 co-op between PS3 and Steam accounts?

Tags: steam, ps3, portal-2

My girlfriend has a PS3 with Portal 2 and our Steam accounts are friends.

Is it possible for us to play in splitscreen mode on the PS3 while saving our progress to our respective Steam accounts?  We would like to be able to play together on the PS3 when we are in the same city, but also be able to play over the internet when we are apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you may not be able to play over PC like kotekzot said, you can still play over PC together. If playing with controllers is preferable to you and you don't want to buy XBox controllers, you can download MotioninJoy ([download here](http://www.motioninjoy.com/)) and play with your PS3 controllers that way.

Good luck with whatever you decide.

Answer (score 0):

[You can't transfer saves between the PC and PS3 versions of Portal 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23405/in-portal-2-can-you-transfer-ps3-saved-data-to-a-pc-to-continue-playing-with-sa). Adding splitscreen play on top of that just adds another layer of "improbable" on top of "impossible".

Comment: You can [play splitscreen on PC](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1847904)...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, but you could drop the PS3 entirely and play split-screen on your computer with the same Steam account, even using your PS3 controller(s) if you want (provided they can connect via USB). However, your new problem comes down to syncing progress between the second player and the second Steam account when you two wish to play remotely.